# Recompile with C-c C-c in AUCTeX

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex

Is therer a way to recompile the document when there were no changes? Currently hitting `C-c C-c` a second time only runs the document viewer (Skim.app in my case).

Comment: If there were no changes at all, there'd be no need to recompile. If you remove the .aux and related files, you can force a rebuild. Not an AUCTeX user, but [this link](http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2008/04/cleaning-up-or-deleting-latex.html) claims to have an easy method for removing the .aux and other files from inside emacs.

Comment: Hitting `C-c C-c` should just give you a suggestion for the command.  Often the suggestion is correct and one hits `RET` to accept it, but there are times when an extra compilation is need (e.g. when using theorem marks from `ntheorem`), and the you can type `L` and TAB-complete to get `LaTeX` as the command.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I sometimes need it when images or other external files have changed.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks, I somehow missed the obvious fact that I can provide a command after hitting `C-c C-c`. Thanks! :)

Comment: @mcb You can walk through the  list of usual commands with arrow down and with arrow up through the list of recently used commands, after C-c C-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting `C-c C-c` should just give you a suggestion for the command.

Often the suggestion is correct and one hits `RET` to accept it, but there are times when an extra compilation is need (e.g. when using theorem marks from `ntheorem`).  It such situations you can type `L`, for example, and TAB-complete to get `LaTeX` as the command.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to use TAB completion, when there are no ambiguities the only known command is executed `;-)`

Comment: @giordano True, but I prefer seeing the name of the completion before starting the command.